# Move a div on clicking on button, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image displayed in a div. I would like to make it move by clicking on a button in the same div. I need this button because clicking ont the image allows to make it move inside the div and I want something else to make the div move.

Here the HTML part:

```
<div  id="jsmolwindow1" style="display:none;">
<script type="text/javascript">
jmolApplet1 = Jmol.getApplet("jmolApplet1", Info);
</script>
<img class="smallButtonidle" id="move" src="ketcher/png/action/arrow.png" style="opacity: 0.8; width=20px height=10px bottom: 20px; right: 20px; float: right;"/>
</div>
```

And here the javascript part:

```
document.getElementById('move').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        div.offsetTop - e.clientY];
}, true);

document.getElementById('move').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

document.getElementById('move').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
        };
        div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
```

This is kind of working, but it is behaving strangely. When I click on the "move" button I can move the div if my mouse stays on the image on the button, but it is kind of hard, and when my mouse move out of this button it is behaving strangely. What I would like is that the image is moving as long as the mouse is pressed on the "move" button. When the user release it, I would like it stop being active.

I hope this question is not too messy, thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you jsfiddle.net this question?

Comment: Try doing your `mousemove` on your `document`, this will avoid any weird glitches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

When the green area dragged, it would move the blue square.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div id='move' style='background-color: blue; width:10px; height:10px; top: 100px; left:100px; position:absolute;'></div>
<div id='touchpad' style='background-color: green; width:400px; height:300px; bottom: 0px; right:0px; position:absolute;'></div>
<script>
var isDown = false;
var div = document.getElementById('move');
var touchpad = document.getElementById('touchpad');
touchpad.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        div.offsetTop - e.clientY];
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
        };
        div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have it behaving properly, I changed two things: the button and the js.
Here how it is now:
HTML:

```
<div  id="jsmolwindow1" style="display:none;">
<script type="text/javascript">
jmolApplet1 = Jmol.getApplet("jmolApplet1", Info);
</script>
<input id="move" class="smallButtonidle" type="button" value="M" style="bottom: 10px; right: 10px; float: right;"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('move').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [div.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        div.offsetTop - e.clientY];
}, true);

document.getElementById('move').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {
            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY
        };
        div.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        div.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
```

Ir works fine. But how to proceed if I don't have one bur several div to associate withe several move buttons?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like all you need is some sort of loop. But this is not an anwer - you can post a new question and link to this one there :)